# Conjugacy classes of $S_n$ under the action of $S_{n-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I try to get explicitly сonjugacy classes of $S_n$ under the action of $S_{n-1}$. I believe that in the description of the classes present cycle type of a permutation and yet another parameter. But I can not get the final result.

Comment: Which action of $S_{n-1}$?  Do you specifically mean the permutations of $1\ldots (n-1)$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, yes, You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What conjugation by an element of $S_{n-1}$ preserves is the cycle structure *plus* the length of the cycle that position $n$ is part of.

Thus each conjugacy class of $S_n$ splits into one class for each *different*  length cycle in its cycle structure.